# Gutenberg: Sidebar for specific post type

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I'm trying to figure out a way, to create a Gutenberg sidebar that is only visible on a custom post type.

For instance, I'd like my sidebar with settings, like a custom checkbox, only related to pages, to be inaccessible on my custom post types.

Instead of creating a sidebar for a specific post type, it would also be great to remove a sidebar from a specific post type.

I couldn't yet find any way to accomplish that, any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this question is a few months old by now, but I got around this issue using the following code and thought it might be helpful for others. There might be a better way, but this works:

```
import ColorSchemeSelect from "./components/color-scheme-select";
import includes from "lodash/includes";

const { select } = wp.data;
const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
const { PluginSidebar } = wp.editPost;

registerPlugin('ahr-sidebar-post-options', {
  render() {
    const postType = select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType();
    if ( !includes(["post", "page"], postType) ) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <PluginSidebar name="ahr-sidebar-post-options" icon="admin-customizer" title="Color settings">
        <div style={{ padding: 16 }}>
          <ColorSchemeSelect />
        </div>
      </PluginSidebar>
    );
  },
});
```

In my example I only wanted to show a certain sidebar for posts and pages, so I'm using `!includes(["post", "page"], postType)` to test wheter or not the sidebar should be shown. If you only want it for one specific post type you'd just go `postType === "my-post-type"` instead.

Comment: I can't really test it out atm but I will in the near future on a new web project, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

To add a sidebar to a custom post type, just add the sidebar after the condition:

```
class SidebarRender extends Component {
  [...]
}

var postType = select("core/editor").getCurrentPostType();
if (postType === "my_post_type")
  registerPlugin("my-sidebar", {
    icon: "excerpt-view",
    render: SidebarRender
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wait until dom is ready before to get the current post type. 
If you don't wait, the selector will return `null`

```
import domReady from '@wordpress/dom-ready';
import { Component } from '@wordpress/element';
import { select } from '@wordpress/data';

class MySidebarPlugin extends Component {
    [...]
}

domReady(() => {
    if (select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType() !== 'post') return;

    registerPlugin('my-sidebar-plugin', {
        icon: 'admin-plugins',
        render: MySidebarPlugin,
    });
});
```